# Opening a specific viewcontroller after popping local notification

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a tabbarcontroller, in one tab it has a navigationcontroller with tableview controller.And there are different kinds of test-daily,weekly ans so on.
I want to make a daily localnotification,so when user touches it,my app loads,tabbar contrlorer selects that one navcon(i know how to do that) and then it selects a specific row in the table-how can i do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have to supply a [userInfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/userInfo) property with your `UILocalNotification` (for the application to know which notification has been triggered later on)

With the help of `userInfo`, you can push the right `UIViewController` onto the viewController-stack.

To respond to opening the app with a shown notification, you have to implement the following method:

[– application:didReceiveLocalNotification:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidReceiveLocalNotification%3a)

Just note the following:

> If you implement application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: to handle an incoming push notification that causes the launch of the application, this method is not invoked for that push notification.

Comment: The question is how to choose the row in table, because selectRow does't work)

Comment: You have to call the implementation of the delegate method itself

Comment: implement application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is pretty crucial, though. The alternative was deprecated, I believe

Comment: Note that – application:didReceiveLocalNotification: is only useful for a notification that fires when your app is open. Otherwise you need to use application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: see fisk's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The app delegate will be passed the local notification in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. The `userInfo` dictionary will contain the notification in the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`.
Note that the application can be launched already but be inactive, and then when the user enter the application the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method will not be called. To see the notification anyway, use the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` app delegate method instead.

When you have this working, it's a simple matter of navigating to the right view by selecting the right tab, selecting the cell in the table view etc, which should be straight forward.